# Fantasy novel set in alternate England, lord of the Rings feel, Villains with red hands

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a trilogy series I read 10 years ago. It was set in a fantasy world with maps looking like England but celtic type names. The main character was a young man, orphan I think, and there was a wizard who mentored him. There was magic and a lot about Leylines and Stones that mirrored Stonehenge. The main villains were like monks but were blind and had red hands.

Comment: You say "Lord of the Rings feel", I hear Sword of Shannara. I never read this book so I can't be sure if it fits your other criterion.

Comment: I found the book series two weeks ago, it's Robert Carter "The Language of Stones". Thank you :)

Comment: Then you should submit that as the answer